# angular-gridster2: resize not resizing inner child

Tags: highcharts, angular8, angular-gridster2

I am using angular 8, Highcharts and angular-gridster2 to drag-select-resize grid.  When I am resizing a widget, the child components (in my case Highcharts chart) does not resize until after the user resizes the screen (browser window).  I added all possible options to the Highcharts options to get it, resize with the (external) window resize. Is there something I am missing, what should I use to fix the issue?
Thank

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in an online code editor like codesandbox? You can use this demo as a template: https://codesandbox.io/s/543l0p0qq4

Comment: Hi @WojciechChmiel, I have updated the code, Please have a look it,  https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-1ocjb open up the view in full screen view, you can see two grid items; try to resize the grid it won't change the inner viz size.

Comment: If a div is resized chart is not resized automatically. You have to call `chart.reflow()` to change its dimensions (API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#reflow). So in your case, you should use some `gridster` resize callback to call `chart.reflow()`.

Comment: Thank you @WojciechChmiel. I updated the demo 
 https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-8w4ut

Comment: Somehow the initial demo link was updated with the latest source code, to make it in sync, I have created another demo link which has initial link source code https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-mh90t